# CS50P PSET8: is datetime.date.today() necessary for cs50p pset 8?

Tags: python, cs50

I am having trouble figuring out this pset. Every time, I use check50 it shows many red faces.
My main problem is when using check50 and nothing is being outputted but, when I run the program locally it outputs the correct sentence.

```
from datetime import date
import sys
import re
# pip imported library to convert numbers into word format
from num2words import num2words


def main():
    print(convert(input("Date of Birth: ")))


def convert(dob):
    # Validates user input
    if re.search(r'^([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])$', dob):
        today = date.today()
        try:
            # Validate date format
            input_date = date.fromisoformat(dob)
        except ValueError:
            sys.exit("Invalid Date")
    # Calulations
    minus = today - input_date
    calculation = minus.days * 24 * 60
    word_form = num2words(calculation)

    # removes the word 'and'
    final = re.sub(r' and', '', word_form)

    return f'{final.capitalize()} minutes'

else:
    sys.exit("Invalid Date")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YYGX.png)

I've tried hard coded the "today's date" the check50 uses to verify my program correctness however,  there are different dates so hard coding the date isn't going to work. Another thing I've tried was  pytesting and all my test were correct?

Comment: Please don't assume we know the CS50 problem sets. What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Create a program that takes a users birthday as input and converts it into minutes via word form
This can be implemented using datetime.minute or time.minute
User input must follow 24 hour format YYYY-MM-DD
If input does not follow the format sys.exit(1) program

Comment: Also, [please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, since you didn't include it in your post - this is the [Seasons of Love problem](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/8/seasons/).

Yes, `datetime.date.today()` is required.  The Check50 tests are using unit test mocking to set the date returned by `datetime.date.today()` to 2000-1-1  whenever it is run so that the tests don't depend on the date that you are submitting the test to determine what the expected answers should be.

The problem is that you're expected to use the `inflect` module instead of `num2words`.  This is indicated under the collapsed hints (In my opinion it should be listed in the main spec).  I tried to use num2words the first time also and I can't recall if the issue is that it is not available to check50 resulting in an import error, or if there is some subtle difference in the output that makes it fail.